# How to render html tag on React while fetching data from json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to render HTML tag on React while fetching data from json. In my json data contains `<h2>` tag but it fails to render `<h2>` tag.

here is  my code

```
const [items, setItems] = useState({"data" : `"<h2>hi</h2>, this is a car"`})
return (
        <div>
          <p>{items.data}</p>
        </div>
)
```

The output is coming as

```
"<h2>hi</h2>, this is a car"
```

but expected output should be

**hi** ,this is a car

Comment: Even though @norbitrial solution should do the trick for you you should avoid HTML injection at all cost. Even the function name indicates it should be treated carefully. Its probably better to adjust the json response (if u can) and use conditional rendering over the html injection. Just my personal opinion of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) for that purpose, read from the documentation:

> `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is React’s replacement for using `innerHTML` in the browser DOM.

Try as the following:

```
function createMarkup(data) {
  return { __html: data };
}

return <div>
    <p><div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(items.data)} /></p>
</div>
```

Important note also from the docs:

> In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and pass an object with a `__html` key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your data is static instead of setting it as a string set it as a JSX element and that should take care of rendering html

```
const Data = () => (<><h2>hi</h2>, this is a car</>)
const [items, setItems] = useState({data : <Data />})
return (
   <div>
     <p>{items.data}</p>
   </div>
)
```

Comment: Without an explanation, it is hard to understand if and why this answers the question. Please edit your answer to make it more clear.